# Como decrementar tempo do TimeSpan?

Tags: c#, .net, time, timespan

Preciso colocar um horário dentro do `TimeSpan`, e fazer com que ele diminua o tempo. Quando chegar a [00:00:00], para o tempo. Preciso fazer neste formato: [00:00:00] - hora, minuto e segundo.

Abaixo, coloquei 5 min.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TimeSpan tp = new TimeSpan(5, 0, 0);
    string horario = "horario do timespan decrementado aqui";
}
```

É como se fosse o cronômetro, coloco um tempo e quando chega a um limite, para tudo. O limite neste caso, aqui, seria o [00:00:00].

Comment: Resolveu Sergio ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis sim!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não gosto muito desta solução, mas seria isto:

```
tp = tp - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/DifferenceTime.cs).

Answer (score 1):

Uma observação: se você quer 5 minutos, o parâmetro é o segundo do construtor do `TimeSpan`.

Imagino que tenha colocado o intervalo do `timer1` para 1000 ms, Seu código deve ser algo assim:

```
TimeSpan tp = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tp = tp - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    string horario = tp.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");
}
```

Fiz um exemplo no SQLFiddle, sem computar o intervalo:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/EXZ4Zf